# PGVector SQLAlchemy <2.0

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

is it possible to use PGVector Vector model, using `SQLAlchemy < 2.0` ? I can't update SQLAlchemy bcs graphene-sqlalchemy-filter is conflicted with it. Can I inject Vector to db using from sqlalchemy.Column. In pgvector tutorial they are using mapped_column.

I was trying using CustomTypes from SQLAlchemy

Comment: Yes, it is possible to use PGVector Vector model with SQLAlchemy < 2.0. According to the PGVector documentation.

Comment: Can u explain how or send link. I see only version with mapped_column.